# Giving resources directly to other citizens in Die2Nite

Tags: die2nite

Is it possible to directly give an item to another player in Die2Nite? I want to give a friend some resources that I picked up, but I don't want to go outside, and I don't want to go through the bank.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. You can visit their home and choose to leave them a message. You can then attach objects to a message and leave it in their home.

If they are not at home, you can also 'discreetly donate an object' which means they don't know you gave it to them.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to the house of the player, there's an option to leave them a message. Click on that, and you'll notice beneath the body of the message the option to attach an object to the note. You can attach as many objects as you wish; they can be either from your inventory or from your house's chest.

Answer (score 3):

You can attach objects to personal messages, just got to your home, create a message and attach something.